# Code Igniter Model unable to use url->segment

Tags: codeigniter

this error arises when I try to get url segement

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Site::$url

Filename: core/Model.php

[This is the code of model class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQxxf.png)
Model[and this is function in controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vx5de.png)
Controller

View

Comment: Just tip next time try not to show image of your code add the code in to your question

Answer (score 2):

Replace url with uri

```
$this->uri->segment(3);
```

Comment: this means Site/Delete/fname
here fname is the 2 segment?

Comment: @JunaidYousafLodhi don't forget to accept answer if worked.